# Change EFI partition umask to 0022 - security issue?

Tags: permissions, security, uefi, boot-loader

I'm working on a program that needs read-only access to the boot-loaders installed - configurations, types, etc. Since I don't want to give the program root privileges, I was thinking about changing the umask of `/boot/efi` to 0022.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would be a security risk?

Comment: Possibly. Ubuntu used defaults until 14.04 then changed to 0077. I change mine back to defaults as I also use ESP for UEFI updates & have multiple installs and often have to edit entries. Boot-Repair also changes mount to defaults. I may change settings back tto 0077, but have not, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Hopefully there is a document somewhere that explains why Ubuntu made this change. I would have to imagine that what I want to do is safer than giving my script root privileges.

Comment: Found this in my notes: Setting defaults: What this will do is mount the partition with owner = root but with read / write permissions ( umask=007 ) granted to all local login users ( gid=46 ). I do not think I ever saw why changed to 0077, but was back in 2014 or before, so any info would be from then.

Comment: I just tried it and the umask is 0022, root:root owner/group.

Comment: Windows formats normally are root. You then set permissions for the entire mount in fstab. Windows formats do not support Linux type ownership & permissions, so only defaults on mount are used. I have seem this. uid=1000,gid=1000 so then user 1000 is owner which is first login.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420861&p=13865822#post13865822